# Dynamicly insert object / array info in a dynamic textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, object

I have a load of objects with arrays in them.

```
var tabData0: Object = new Object();
tabData0.tab1 = new Object();
tabData0.tab1.names = new Array();
tabData0.tab1.names.push("<b>111.</b> Het systeem aan- of uitzetten", "<b>2.</b> De  temperatuur verhogen of verlagen");

var tabData1: Object = new Object();
tabData1.tab1 = new Object();
tabData1.tab1.names = new Array();
tabData1.tab1.names.push("<b>222.</b> Het systeem aan- of uitzetten 2", "<b>23.</b> De  temperatuur verhogen of verlagen");
```

The idea is to pick from one of those objects and insert the contents into a texfield.

I retreive a var from 3 levels up and store it, then combine it with tabData.

```
var moveRemoteHolder = MovieClip(parent.parent.parent).remoteHolder;
var all = "tabData"+moveRemoteHolder;
trace ("all = " +all); // returns: all = tabData0
```

I want to combine this output with a few more to refer to my object / array.
The `remoteHolder` contains the value I need to know which object (`tabData0`, `tabData1`, etc) to  retrieve the info from.

```
tabHolder['btn' + i].titleHolder.titleField.htmlText = all['tab' + tab].names[(i-1)];
```

But get this:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property tab1 not found on String and there is no default value.
```

Comment: Is `all` an array? What's in it? What do you mean by `all['tab' + tab]`? What is `names`? You should edit your question with a few more details about your data and what you want to do.

Comment: You need to declare types with your vars.  For example:  "var all:Array = ... ".  Your code is very hard to understand without the type declarations.  Also - what is moveRemoteHolder meant to be?  Glad to answer if you can provide more info.

Comment: I have made it more clear @RossSmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** based on comments on this answer from OP.  See revised code snippet.

I can see why the results are confusing.  You are tracing out "tabData0" because:

1. var all is untyped
2. var moveRemoteHolder is untyped
3. MovieClip is a dynamic class
4. remoteHolder is undefined on MovieClip(parent.parent.parent)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=kwRvoeGsuY8

I recommend this instead:

```
var dataContainer:MovieClip = MovieClip(parent.parent.parent);
var all:Object = dataContainer["tabData" + dataContainer["moveRemoteHolder"]];
trace ("all = " + all);
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks @RossSmith!
tabData0 + tabData1 are defined in the same space as these lines of code are.
The var moveRemoteHolder is filled with the value from a var from three levels up. 
I had this working before:
    tabHolder['btn' + i].titleHolder.titleField.htmlText = tabData['tab' + tab].names[(i-1)];'

The thing that has changed now is that there are more "tabDatas" and I want to dynamicly address the right one. That's what the moveRemoteHolder var was for.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the information in your comment.  Check the answer code example.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try it. Will let you know if I get it working.
It's hard making your question clear when you've been staring at your code for hours...